# Export an entire virtual server - IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

My customer has a system that deployed in virtual server IBM Cloud (Softlayer infra before) Is there a way to export an entire virtual server to ova/ovf file?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never done this. This link shows how to export a Classic VM to COS in preparation for migration to VPC: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc-on-classic-vsi?topic=vpc-on-classic-vsi-migrate-vsi-from-classic-infra-to-vpc-on-classic&locale=se

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to export a Softlayer Virtual Machine in VHD format.  There is a great blog post on this topic here https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/automate-the-migration-of-a-workload-based-on-virtual-servers

The basic steps to create the VHD image are:

1. Create a Cloud Object Storage, COS, instance
2. Create a regional COS bucket
3. Export the Softlayer Virtual Server Instance (create an Image Template)
4. Export the Image into the COS bucket

You can then download the VHD from from the COS bucket to a computer that has a vhd to ova/ovf converter (sorry I have not done that part)